# PowerShell won't start job

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0, job-control

I have the following PowerShell 5 program:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK}
Wait-Job $job
```

When I run it, it terminates immediately with the following output:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK
```

and `timeout.exe` does not appear in Task Manager.

Why does it not wait 10 seconds before terminating? When I invoke `timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK` outside a job, it does wait 10 seconds, as does invoking `Start-Sleep 10` in a job.

I am not looking for a different way to solve the same problem (sleeping), but specifically for an answer to *why* this program behaves the way it does.

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK}`

Comment: I mean, `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK}}`

Comment: you can use Invoke-Command as job so it will run as a Background Job and you can receive it as well using _Receive-Job_ as like this:

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {timeout.exe 10 /NOBREAK} -AsJob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that for timeout.exe to catch a Ctrl+C, it redirects the input, which doesn't work in a background job. Obviously if all you want to do is sleep, then Start-Sleep would work.

You can view the output of your job, and the error message by doing:

```
Receive-Job 1
```